# Web ApI: HttpClient is not invoking my web api action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

See first how i design my web api action.

```
[System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/Appointments")]
public class AppointmentsServiceController : ApiController
{

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet, System.Web.Http.Route("UserAppointments/{email}")]
    public IHttpActionResult UserAppointments(string email)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            AppointmentsService _appservice = new AppointmentsService();
            IEnumerable<Entities.Appointments> app = _appservice.GetUserWiseAppointments(email);

            if (app.Count() <= 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok(app);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();

        }

    }
}
```

Now this way i am calling web api action from my asp.net mvc action by HttpClient.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> List()
    {

        var fullAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseAddress"] + "api/Appointments/UserAppointments/" + Session["useremail"];

        IEnumerable<Entities.Appointments> app = null;
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var response = client.GetAsync(fullAddress).Result)
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var customerJsonString = await  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        app = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Entities.Appointments>>(customerJsonString);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
                        var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                        //MessageBox.Show(dict["Message"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            // catch any exception here
        }

        return View();
    }
 }
```

i want capture the return IEnumerable and if not data return that also i have to capture. please show me the right direction.

Where i made the mistake. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing async with blocking calls like `.Result`

```
var response = client.GetAsync(fullAddress).Result
```

And

```
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

can lead to deadlocks, which is possibly why it it not hitting your API.

Refactor the code to be async all the way.

That would mean updating the `using` to

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(fullAddress)
```

and the reading of the content in the `else` statement to

```
await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not awaiting your GetAsync call, so in the following `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)` is probably always returning false. Try calling your method like this:

```
using (var response = (await client.GetAsync(fullAddress)).Result)
{
```